# Lambda function timing out after 10 seconds

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, bookshelf.js

Code:

```
const knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
        host: process.env.database_host,
        user: process.env.database_user,
        password: process.env.database_pass,
        database: process.env.database_db,
        charset: 'utf8'
    }
});
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);
const User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users'
});

const checkValues = (values) => {
    // todo: add data validation
    return true;
};

exports.test = (database) => {
    // todo: add tests
};

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    let salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync();

    let values = {
        first_name: event.firstname,
        last_name: event.lastname,
        username: event.username,
        date_of_birth: event.birthday,
        password: bcrypt.hashSync(event.password, salt),
        password_salt: salt
    };

    if (!checkValues(values)) {
        callback(null, {
            success: false,
            error: {
                id: 2,
                details: 'data validation error'
            }
        });

        context.done(null, "User not created");

        return;
    }

    try {
        new User({
            'first_name': values.first_name,
            'last_name': values.last_name,
            'username': values.username,
            'date_of_birth': values.date_of_birth,
            'password': values.password,
            'password_salt': values.password_salt
        }).save();

        callback(null, {
            success: true
        });

        context.done(null, "User created");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);

        callback(null, {
            success: false,
            error: {
                id: 1,
                details: 'error inserting user into database'
            }
        });

        context.done(null, "User not created");
    }
};
```

I am trying to make a basic sign up api endpoint using AWS API Gateway and Lambda functions, however every time I post the information to the api gateway I get the error

```
{
    "errorMessage": "2017-09-07T08:38:50.174Z f2368466-93a7-11e7-b4bc-01142a109ede Task timed out after 10.00 seconds"
}
```

I have tried using different database libraries but I seem to always be hitting the same problem. The database connection works I know this because the user does infact get added to the users table in the database and the password is successfully hashed..

I have also tried using asynchronous bcrypt but it doesn't make any difference to the result, it still does it but says it times out.

Lambda doesn't seem to be terminating properly, something keeps the process still running and I can't figure out what, any ideas?

Comment: increase timeout for lamda function.Timeout value setting is under advanced setting tab of Lamda

Comment: I just set it to 1 minute and now got the response{
    "message": "Endpoint request timed out"
}

Comment: Cloud watch says 2017-09-07T08:51:45.914Z a2d00f90-93a9-11e7-9c18-ab652d60fde4 Task timed out after 60.00 seconds

Comment: max value you can configure  for lamda is 300 sec.Configure timeout value to 5 min and check Note:: Your program execution should get finished within 5 min.

Comment: `09:03:15 2017-09-07T09:03:15.958Z af0a4a81-93aa-11e7-9c58-0bc605599eab Task timed out after 300.00 seconds` Still just times out

Comment: You need to check your code.Your program execution time should not exceed the 5 min.Check your external services call,DB connection.

Comment: Well obviously... it shouldn't even take a second to put something in a database... How do I debug that information?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153850/discussion-between-vaibs-and-user2710382).

Comment: It sounds like you need to either set `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false` inside the handler function... or disconnect from the database.  The lingering connection will otherwise keep the Lambda process running.

Comment: Thank you @Michael-sqlbot this is sort of working now haha, are there any drawbacks from using this? And would it be better if I closed the database connection?

Comment: There are reasons to use this and reasons not to.  How often is the function invoked?  What is the likelihood of concurrent invocations?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot well at the moment the function barely ever gets called but the idea of it is going to be a chat app so i don't know how many people will be using it daily...

Answer (score 1):

i had the similar issue using API gateway invoking my lambda.

The default timeout for API gateway is 30 seconds. If your response is not ready within in 30 seconds, you will be timed out though your lambda would still run!

So may be try to get the response back within 30 seconds. If not have one lambda being invoked from the API and give the response back immediately and let the first lambda invoke your second lambda and that will run upto max time which is 5 mins.

Thanks